# How can I customize Slider widget in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, slider

Is it possible to customize a Slider Widget in Flutter?

Like  this:

[image]

Comment: If you ask about Slider thumb Image, please check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58116843/flutter-how-to-add-thumb-image-to-slider

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Wrap your slider with a SliderTheme

```
SliderTheme(
    data: SliderThemeData(
            thumbColor: Colors.green,
            thumbShape: RoundSliderThumbShape(enabledThumbRadius: 20)),
    child: Slider(
          value: _value,
          onChanged: (val) {
            _value = val;
            setState(() {});
          },
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: But how to add custom Icon on thumbShape? –

Comment: You have to  create a custom thumb by extending from `SliderComponentShape`  and override the  `paint` method. Then, inside the `paint` method use `context.canvas` to draw your custom shape. Check `canvas.drawImage` to use an image if you want to use an image.

Comment: @MarcelGolob this blog post discuss how to do it: https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-sliders-demystified-4b3ea65879c

Answer (score 13):

I think you have to use the SliderTickMarkShape class

> Base class for Slider tick mark shapes.
>
> Create a subclass of this if you would like a custom slider tick mark
>   shape.

The easy way is to get the actual SliderTheme used in your context and modify only the properties you need. For example, to modify one slide:

```
SliderTheme(
    data: SliderTheme.of(context).copyWith(
    activeTrackColor: Colors.white,
    thumbShape: RoundSliderThumbShape(enabledThumbRadius: 15.0),
    overlayShape: RoundSliderOverlayShape(overlayRadius: 30.0),
    ),
    child: Slider(
             value: height.toDouble(),
             min: 120.0,
             max: 220.0,
             activeColor: Colors.white,
             inactiveColor: Color(0xFF8D8E98),
             onChanged: (double newValue) {
                 setState(() {
                        height = newValue.round();
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                ),
```

Another option is modify the theme you're using in your app; in this way you modify all the sliders in the app:

```
MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
          sliderTheme: SliderTheme.of(context).copyWith( //slider modifications
            thumbColor: Color(0xFFEB1555),
            inactiveTrackColor: Color(0xFF8D8E98),
            activeTrackColor: Colors.white,
            overlayColor: Color(0x99EB1555),
            thumbShape: RoundSliderThumbShape(enabledThumbRadius: 15.0),
            overlayShape: RoundSliderOverlayShape(overlayRadius: 30.0),
          ),
          primaryColor: Color(0xFF0A0E21), // theme color
          scaffoldBackgroundColor: Color(0xFF0A0E21)), // theme background color
      home: InputPage(),
);
```

Answer (score 5):

I remember , I had the same challenge.

I create my own wave slider:

```
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

List<int> bars = [];
const barWidth = 5.0;
double screenWidth;
int numberOfBars;

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Home(),
    );
  }
}

void randomNumberGenerator() {
  Random r = Random();
  for (var i = 0; i < numberOfBars; i++) {
    bars.add(r.nextInt(40) + 10);
  }
}

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (bars.isEmpty) {
      screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
      numberOfBars = screenWidth ~/ barWidth;
      randomNumberGenerator();
    }
    return Container(child: WaveSlider());
  }
}

class WaveSlider extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => WaveSliderState();
}

class WaveSliderState extends State<WaveSlider> {
  double bar2Position = 180.0;

  _onTapDown(TapDownDetails details) {
    var x = details.globalPosition.dx;
    print("tap down " + x.toString());
    setState(() {
      bar2Position = x;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    int barItem = 0;
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Stack(
          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
          children: <Widget>[
            GestureDetector(
              onTapDown: (TapDownDetails details) => _onTapDown(details),
              onHorizontalDragUpdate: (DragUpdateDetails details) {
                setState(() {
                  bar2Position = details.globalPosition.dx;
                });
              },
              child: Container(
                child: Row(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: bars.map((int height) {
                    Color color = barItem + 1 < bar2Position / barWidth
                        ? Colors.deepPurple
                        : Colors.blueGrey;
                    barItem++;
                    return Container(
                      color: color,
                      height: height.toDouble(),
                      width: 5.0,
                    );
                  }).toList(),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```