# Flutter: How to add thumb Image to Slider?

Tags: flutter

I tried to add an image to slider thumb, but I haven't an idea of how it should work. At `SliderThemeData` we haven't parameters for adding thumb image.

I have already tied to use `SliderComponentShape` for drawing thumb, but it didn't work.

```
class TimeReportTextField extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TimeReportTextFieldState createState() => _TimeReportTextFieldState();
}

class _TimeReportTextFieldState extends State<TimeReportTextField> {
  final textFieldController = TextEditingController();
  ui.Image customImage;

  Future<ui.Image> load(String asset) async {
    ByteData data = await rootBundle.load(asset);
    ui.Codec codec = await ui.instantiateImageCodec(data.buffer.asUint8List());
    ui.FrameInfo fi = await codec.getNextFrame();
    return fi.image;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    load('images/slider_thumb.png').then((image) {
      setState(() {
        customImage = image;
      });
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    textFieldController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                Radius.circular(3),
              ),
              border: Border.all(color: Color(0xFFF4F4F4))),
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(12),
          child: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                child: Text(
                  'STD',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontFamily: 'SF-Pro',
                      fontSize: 13,
                      color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.4)),
                ),
              ),
              Flexible(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 8),
                  child: TextField(
                    controller: textFieldController,
                    textAlign: TextAlign.end,
                    textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(border: InputBorder.none),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 32.5),
          child: SliderTheme(
            data: SliderThemeData(
              activeTrackColor: Colors.red,
              inactiveTrackColor: Colors.transparent,
              thumbShape: SliderThumbImage(customImage),
            ),
            child: Slider(
              onChanged: (value) {},
              value: 0.5,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class SliderThumbImage extends SliderComponentShape {
  final ui.Image image;

  SliderThumbImage(this.image);

  @override
  Size getPreferredSize(bool isEnabled, bool isDiscrete) {
    return Size(5, 5);
  }

  @override
  void paint(PaintingContext context, Offset center,
      {Animation<double> activationAnimation,
      Animation<double> enableAnimation,
      bool isDiscrete,
      TextPainter labelPainter,
      RenderBox parentBox,
      SliderThemeData sliderTheme,
      TextDirection textDirection,
      double value}) {
    var canvas = context.canvas;

    canvas.drawImage(image, Offset(5, 5), new Paint());
  }
}
```

Comment: check my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/73872457/2126077

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've already fixed my problem.

```
import 'dart:ui' as ui;

class SliderThumbImage extends SliderComponentShape {
    final ui.Image image;

    SliderThumbImage(this.image);

    @override
    Size getPreferredSize(bool isEnabled, bool isDiscrete) {
        return Size(0, 0);
    }

    @override
    void paint(PaintingContext context, Offset center,
        {Animation<double> activationAnimation,
        Animation<double> enableAnimation,
        bool isDiscrete,
        TextPainter labelPainter,
        RenderBox parentBox,
        SliderThemeData sliderTheme,
        TextDirection textDirection,
        double value}) {
    final canvas = context.canvas;
    final imageWidth = image?.width ?? 10;
    final imageHeight = image?.height ?? 10;

    Offset imageOffset = Offset(
        center.dx - (imageWidth / 2),
        center.dy - (imageHeight / 2),
    );

    Paint paint = Paint()..filterQuality = FilterQuality.high;

    if (image != null) {
        canvas.drawImage(image, imageOffset, paint);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: hi, is there a way we can adjust the height / width of the image?

Comment: How can i convert flutter Image to dart ui.Image ?

Comment: @VickySalunkhe , you can adjust it like this 

`ui.Codec codec = await ui.instantiateImageCodec(data.buffer.asUint8List(),targetWidth: 30,targetHeight: 30);`

Comment: but paint method gives an error when I use it

Comment: You should set the thumb dimensions in ```getPreferredSize``` to the image width and height. Otherwise, slider won't be laid out properly and the entire thumb may not be draggable.

Answer (score 1):

This Library can be used to add image to the slider thumb easily

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_xlider

```
         FlutterSlider(
          values: [40],
          max: 100,
          min: 0,
         
          handler: FlutterSliderHandler(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(),
            child: Material(
              type: MaterialType.canvas,
              elevation: 3,
              child: Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom:4),
                  child: Image.asset(Assets.filter_thumb)),
            ),
          ),
          onDragging: (handlerIndex, lowerValue, upperValue) {
            
          },
        );
```

Comment: This library has multiple issues. First there's a not a null safe release yet. To get a null safe version, you have to download the source code and include the project in pubspec.yaml. Secondly, the thumb is drawn with an incorrect size. Thirdly, the thumb still moves even if you click outside the rendered thumb.