# How to create a range slider with an image thumb that animates to a position on a button tap in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, layout, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I'm a beginner in Flutter. I'm trying to make a custom range slider with an image as the thumb. I tried to achieve this using the [flutter_xlider](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_xlider) package which lets to add an image thumb but had no utility methods to control the slider from a button.

Here is the range slider that I wish to do. But rather than sliding the thumb to change the values, how can I programatically slide this with a button?

How can I do this? Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l9uHB8VXZOg&t=4s

Comment: You can use default Material slider in flutter. Have a look [here](https://www.fluttertpoint.com/slider-in-flutter), its easy and cool.

Comment: Can I add an image as a thumb in Material Slider?

Comment: No, Use another way for that. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58116843/flutter-how-to-add-thumb-image-to-slider

Answer (score 0):

What if you change the values of the slider:

```
double _currentValue = 0.0;

FlutterSlider(
  values: [_currentValue],
  max: 500,
  min: 0,
  onDragging: (handlerIndex, lowerValue, upperValue) {
    _lowerValue = lowerValue;
    _upperValue = upperValue;
    setState(() {});
  },
)

//call this with buttons
void _changeValue(double newValue){
  _currentValue = newValue;
  setState((){});
}
```

Comment: This is something that I thought too. But doing so, would not have animations. That's the let-down. Do you know how to animate this while using setState to update the value?

Comment: i afraid not bro, it doesn't provide controller for that...