# How to give rectangular shape to the thumb icon in slider in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-slider

i am learning flutter. I used Slider class to create slider ( in android its called Seekbar ), here i want to change the thumb icon to rectangular shape, it is possible or not, Please let me know any solution for this?

```
SliderTheme.of(context).copyWith(
                      trackShape: CustomTrackShape(),
                      thumbShape: RoundSliderThumbShape(
                        enabledThumbRadius: 15,
                        disabledThumbRadius: 5,
                      ),

                  ),
                  child: Slider(
                    inactiveColor: Colors.black12,
                    value: _sliderValue,
                    min: 5000,
                    max: 500000,
                    divisions: 1000,
                    label: _sliderValue.round().toString(),
                    onChanged: (value) {
                      setState(() {
                        _sliderValue = value;
                        print("slider value" + _sliderValue.toString());
                        // _amountController.text = value.floor().toString();
                        _amountController.text =
                            getChangedAmount(value.floor().toString());
                        // print("amount controller value" + _amountController.text);
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                ),
```

[image]

** I want below type **

[image]

Comment: can you update image your current result and code?

Comment: @RavindraS.Patil, Updated my answer, Please check.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to customize Slider widget in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57057765/how-to-customize-slider-widget-in-flutter)

Comment: Thankx for your suggestion, but i have an issue while @overriding the  "void paint()" method.  Error is -> The method 'SliderThumbImage.paint' has fewer named arguments than those of overridden method 'SliderComponentShape.paint'.

Comment: @Rakesh Saini,I think your solution here https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-sliders-demystified-4b3ea65879c

Comment: There is also same code, still have an issue.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a custom `thumbShape` using [SliderComponentShape](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SliderComponentShape-class.html). In my implementation, I just modified the paint in the default [RoundSliderThumbShape](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/RoundSliderThumbShape-class.html).

```dart
class RectSliderThumbShape extends SliderComponentShape {
  /// Create a slider thumb that draws a Rect.
  const RectSliderThumbShape({
    this.enabledThumbRadius = 10.0,
    this.disabledThumbRadius,
    this.elevation = 1.0,
    this.pressedElevation = 6.0,
  });

  /// The preferred radius of the round thumb shape when the slider is enabled.
  ///
  /// If it is not provided, then the Material Design default of 10 is used.
  final double enabledThumbRadius;

  /// The preferred radius of the round thumb shape when the slider is disabled.
  ///
  /// If no disabledRadius is provided, then it is equal to the
  /// [enabledThumbRadius]
  final double? disabledThumbRadius;
  double get _disabledThumbRadius => disabledThumbRadius ?? enabledThumbRadius;

  /// The resting elevation adds shadow to the unpressed thumb.
  ///
  /// The default is 1.
  ///
  /// Use 0 for no shadow. The higher the value, the larger the shadow. For
  /// example, a value of 12 will create a very large shadow.
  ///
  final double elevation;

  /// The pressed elevation adds shadow to the pressed thumb.
  ///
  /// The default is 6.
  ///
  /// Use 0 for no shadow. The higher the value, the larger the shadow. For
  /// example, a value of 12 will create a very large shadow.
  final double pressedElevation;

  @override
  Size getPreferredSize(bool isEnabled, bool isDiscrete) {
    return Size.fromRadius(isEnabled == true ? enabledThumbRadius : _disabledThumbRadius);
  }

  @override
  void paint(
      PaintingContext context,
      Offset center, {
        required Animation<double> activationAnimation,
        required Animation<double> enableAnimation,
        required bool isDiscrete,
        required TextPainter labelPainter,
        required RenderBox parentBox,
        required SliderThemeData sliderTheme,
        required TextDirection textDirection,
        required double value,
        required double textScaleFactor,
        required Size sizeWithOverflow,
      }) {
    assert(context != null);
    assert(center != null);
    assert(enableAnimation != null);
    assert(sliderTheme != null);
    assert(sliderTheme.disabledThumbColor != null);
    assert(sliderTheme.thumbColor != null);

    final Canvas canvas = context.canvas;
    final Tween<double> radiusTween = Tween<double>(
      begin: _disabledThumbRadius,
      end: enabledThumbRadius,
    );
    final ColorTween colorTween = ColorTween(
      begin: sliderTheme.disabledThumbColor,
      end: sliderTheme.thumbColor,
    );

    final Color color = colorTween.evaluate(enableAnimation)!;
    final double radius = radiusTween.evaluate(enableAnimation);

    final Tween<double> elevationTween = Tween<double>(
      begin: elevation,
      end: pressedElevation,
    );

    final double evaluatedElevation = elevationTween.evaluate(activationAnimation);
    final Path path = Path()
      ..addArc(Rect.fromCenter(center: center, width: 2 * radius, height: 2 * radius), 0, math.pi * 2);

    bool paintShadows = true;
    assert(() {
      if (debugDisableShadows) {
        paintShadows = false;
      }
      return true;
    }());

    if (paintShadows) {
      canvas.drawShadow(path, Colors.black, evaluatedElevation, true);
    }

    // Use drawRect instead of drawCircle
    canvas.drawRect(Rect.fromCircle(center: center, radius: radius),
      Paint()..color = color,
    );
  }
}
```

Then use RectSliderThumbShape on `SliderTheme.thumbShape`

```dart
SliderTheme(
  data: const SliderThemeData(
    thumbColor: Colors.green,
    thumbShape: RectSliderThumbShape()
  ),
  child: Slider(
    value: _currentSliderValue,
    max: 100,
    divisions: 5,
    label: _currentSliderValue.round().toString(),
    onChanged: (double value) {
      setState(() {
        _currentSliderValue = value;
      });
    },
  ),
),
```

Here's how it looks like

[image: Sample Demo]

Comment: How edit this code for insert inside a square container an image?

Answer (score 2):

A simpler version :D

```
class _RectSliderThumbShape extends SliderComponentShape {
  final double width;
  const _RectSliderThumbShape({required this.width});

  @override
  Size getPreferredSize(bool isEnabled, bool isDiscrete) {
    return Size(width, 0);
  }

  @override
  void paint(
    PaintingContext context,
    Offset center, {
    required Animation<double> activationAnimation,
    required Animation<double> enableAnimation,
    required bool isDiscrete,
    required TextPainter labelPainter,
    required RenderBox parentBox,
    required SliderThemeData sliderTheme,
    required TextDirection textDirection,
    required double value,
    required double textScaleFactor,
    required Size sizeWithOverflow,
  }) {
    assert(sliderTheme.thumbColor != null);

    final rect =
        Rect.fromCenter(center: center, width: width, height: context.estimatedBounds.size.height);
    context.canvas.drawRRect(
      RRect.fromRectAndRadius(rect, Radius.circular(width / 2)),
      Paint()..color = sliderTheme.thumbColor!,
    );
  }
}
```