# I would like to know how to create a slider to change the text size

Tags: flutter, flutter-slider

I would like to know how to create a slider to change the text size.

This is the design.
あ = A

i want increase +0.05

[image]

My code is bad . because i can not made same design .

```
  CupertinoSlider(
    min: 0.1,
    max: 0.6,
    value: clockTextSize.toDouble(),
    onChanged: (_value) {
      setState(
        () {
          clockTextSize = _value.toInt();
        },
      );
    },
  )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Note: your question wasn't too clear if you're looking to achieve the same design or regarding the divisions. This answer is how to achieve the same design.*

##### Result

[image]

#### Customization

To customize the `Slider` to your liking, you can use [`SliderTheme`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SliderTheme-class.html). 
Then, to customize the Tick, you can create your own class that `extend`s [`SliderTickMarkShape`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SliderTickMarkShape-class.html).

###### Code

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MaterialApp(debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false, home: Test()));
}

class Test extends StatefulWidget {
  const Test({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Test> createState() => _TestState();
}

class _TestState extends State<Test> {
  var value = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: SizedBox(
          height: 200,
          width: 500,
          child: Card(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
            color: const Color(0xff323237),
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: [
                  const Text(
                    "あ",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: SliderTheme(
                      data: SliderTheme.of(context).copyWith(
                        tickMarkShape: CustomTick(),
                        trackHeight: 10.0,
                        minThumbSeparation: 2,
                        thumbColor: Colors.white,
                        thumbShape: const RoundSliderThumbShape(
                          enabledThumbRadius: 20,
                        ),
                        inactiveTickMarkColor: Colors.grey,
                        inactiveTrackColor: Colors.grey,
                        activeTrackColor: Colors.grey,
                      ),
                      child: Slider(
                        min: 1,
                        max: 100,
                        value: value.toDouble(),
                        divisions: 12,
                        onChanged: (newValue) {
                          setState(() {
                            value = newValue.round();
                          });
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const Text(
                    "あ",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CustomTick extends SliderTickMarkShape {
  @override
  Size getPreferredSize(
      {required SliderThemeData sliderTheme, required bool isEnabled}) {
    return const Size(10, 10);
  }

  @override
  void paint(PaintingContext context, Offset center,
      {required RenderBox parentBox,
      required SliderThemeData sliderTheme,
      required Animation<double> enableAnimation,
      required Offset thumbCenter,
      required bool isEnabled,
      required TextDirection textDirection}) {
    final Canvas canvas = context.canvas;
    final Paint paint = Paint()..color = Colors.grey;

    canvas.drawRect(
        Rect.fromCenter(center: center, width: 5, height: 20), paint);
  }
}
```

##### See also

[How can I customize Slider widget in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57057765/how-to-customize-slider-widget-in-flutter)

Answer (score 1):

> i want increase +0.05

you can set division property to achieve this. see [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/cupertino/CupertinoSlider-class.html)

For example, if `min` is `0.1` and `max` is `0.6` and `divisions` is `5`, then the slider can take on the values discrete values 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, and 0.6.

then in your case, if you want increase `+0.05`, you can set the `division=10`

```
CupertinoSlider(
    min: 0.1,
    max: 0.6,
    division:10,
    ...
```

result:

[image]